# Temperature is not increasing after some value (MAX6675) (PID)

Tags: arduino, temperature, pid-controller, heater

[image]

I was following this circuit diagram shown above (from https://electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut24_sch2.php) to create a 12V heater for heating a hot end using PID.

The only thing I'm not using from the above circuit is the LCD display; instead I'm using a serial monitor to display the values and hard coding the set temperature value. Also I don't have a 12v supply so I'm converting my 25v 14.6A power supply using a buck converter to give out 12v for the above circuit.

The problem I'm facing is that at some point when, temperature reaches some value like 80°C or 70°C (the values varies every time), the temperature stops increasing; It stays there but the set temperature is still far beyond the current temperature eg. 110°C or 200°C etc.

Please help me and let me know what is causing the issue.

```
#include <SPI.h>
//We define the SPI pìns
#define MAX6675_CS   10
#define MAX6675_SO   12
#define MAX6675_SCK  13

//Pins
int PWM_pin = 3;

//Variables
float temperature_read = 0.0;
float set_temperature = 190;
float PID_error = 0;
float previous_error = 0;
float elapsedTime, Time, timePrev;
int PID_value = 0;

//PID constants
int kp = 90, ki = 26, kd = 48;
int PID_p = 0; int PID_i = 0; int PID_d = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("12v PID test:");
  pinMode(PWM_pin,OUTPUT);
  Time = millis(); 
  // wait for MAX chip to stabilize
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  // First we read the real value of temperature
  temperature_read = readThermocouple();
  //Next we calculate the error between the setpoint and the real value
  PID_error = set_temperature - temperature_read + 3;
  //Calculate the P value
  PID_p = 0.01*kp * PID_error;
  //Calculate the I value in a range on +-3
  PID_i = 0.01*PID_i + (ki * PID_error);
  
  //For derivative we need real time to calculate speed change rate
  timePrev = Time; // the previous time is stored before the actual time read
  Time = millis(); // actual time read
  elapsedTime = (Time - timePrev) / 1000; 
  //Now we can calculate the D calue
  PID_d = 0.01 * kd * ((PID_error - previous_error) / elapsedTime);
  //Final total PID value is the sum of P + I + D
  PID_value = PID_p + PID_i + PID_d;

  //We define PWM range between 0 and 255
  if (PID_value < 0) {
    PID_value = 0;
  }
  if (PID_value > 255) {
    PID_value = 255;
  }
  //Now we can write the PWM signal to the mosfet on digital pin D3
  //Since we activate the MOSFET with a 0 to the base of the BJT, we write 255-PID value (inverted)
  analogWrite(PWM_pin, 255-PID_value);
  previous_error = PID_error;     // Remember to store the previous error for next loop.
  delay(250); // Refresh rate
  Serial.println("PID TEMP control"); 
  Serial.print("S:");
  Serial.print(set_temperature);
  Serial.print(" R:");
  Serial.print(temperature_read);
  Serial.print(" PID: ");
  Serial.println(PID_value);
}

double readThermocouple() {
  uint16_t v;
  pinMode(MAX6675_CS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MAX6675_SO, INPUT);
  pinMode(MAX6675_SCK, OUTPUT);
  
  digitalWrite(MAX6675_CS, LOW);
  delay(1);

  // Read in 16 bits,
  //  15    = 0 always
  //  14..2 = 0.25 degree counts MSB First
  //  2     = 1 if thermocouple is open circuit  
  //  1..0  = uninteresting status
  
  v = shiftIn(MAX6675_SO, MAX6675_SCK, MSBFIRST);
  v <<= 8;
  v |= shiftIn(MAX6675_SO, MAX6675_SCK, MSBFIRST);
  
  digitalWrite(MAX6675_CS, HIGH);
  if (v & 0x4) {    
    // Bit 2 indicates if the thermocouple is disconnected
    return NAN;     
  }

  // The lower three bits (0,1,2) are discarded status bits
  v >>= 3;

  // The remaining bits are the number of 0.25 degree (C) counts
  return v * 0.25;
}
```

Comment: What does the Arduino think the temperature is? (you should print that to the monitor)

Comment: Is it the temperature sensing that is the problem or the heater control? Divide the problem.

Comment: What buck converter are you using? What current can it supply? Are you certain that you hot-end heater is rated to run off 12V and not something higher?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yeah I'm printing the sensed temperature to the monitor. It starts from some value like 28C and stop at 70 or 80C.

Comment: @Kartman I don't think temperature sensing is problem.

Comment: @brhans it is LM2596 buck converter. Yeah I'm sure the hot end heater is rated to runn off 12V. And yeah I've tested the heater with my 3d printer it goes to whatever temperature I specify with my 3d printer.

Comment: ... and you've connected it *exactly* as drawn - you haven't connected the heater on the Source side of the MOSFET?

Comment: If the temperature reading stops at 80 and it’s much hotter, then temperature reading is the problem. Are you sure that the sensor is actually a type K thermocouple?

Comment: @brhans yes I've connected it exactly as shown in the diagram.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Temperature reading is not problem with just temperature reading code I tested with candle & read the temperature it goes above 100C easily.
Yeah Im sure it's K type.

Comment: You said it is much hotter than 80°C  but reads 80°C. Is that true? In that case the controller will remain on and it will continue to heat, as it should, since the setpoint has not been reached.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany No no that's not true. When it show 80C and stops there, the heating also stops I touched and sensed it's always same. Sorry for my bad english BTW

Comment: Where did you get the PID controller code from?

Comment: From the same site mentioned above. @SpehroPefhany

Comment: Here is the update, I've removed the buck converter and used SMPS from old desktop to get 12v directly. Now the temperature is rising till 180C. And not going above it.